# How to set the Default value of a Date/Time column to next Friday?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, date-time

I did some poking around in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) for Calculated field formulas, but I don't see anything that would help me do this.  Does anyone know if it can be done?  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Default option you can use [Today] plus some number of days... you would have to find the weekday as an integer, compare it to the weekday of Today as an integer, and do some math to get something to add to [Today] to make it next Friday. I'll see if i can find the right formula for it in the mean time.

Edit: ok so you can use WEEKDAY([Today]) to return an integer from 1 (sunday) to 7 (saturday) ([Options of WEEKDAY Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/weekday-function-HA001161098.aspx)), and depending on how you want to determine what 'next week' is, you would add write the formula as something like...

```
=[Today] + (6 - MOD(WEEKDAY([Today]),7)) + 7
```

Haven't tested it but that should work!

Comment: I ended up using this method which seems a little shorter and also seems to work: `=Today+6-WEEKDAY(Today)`

Comment: The short version isn't working friday or saturday. Where it'll give today or yesterday, which isn't consistent with next friday.

Comment: Quick breakdown on what each version does: long version; takes the weekday number and rearranges it as 0 saturday -> 6 friday, 6 subtracted by it to get the number of days to get to THIS week's friday (so with this setup saturday gives you two full work weeks) and added by 7 to give you the next friday. The short version; return THIS week's friday where friday returns itself and saturday returns the day before.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, I was asked to set a field as the "Second Thursday of Next Month."  Using this post as well as some other tricks I already know, I was able to come up with a formula (shared if other users get the similar request):

```
=DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today)+1,(5-MOD(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today)+1,1)),7)+8))
```

Because you aren't adding the values to a "Today" field (which would be the first of the month), you add 8 instead of 7 to account for the first day.

Answer (score 0):

The below formula returns the date of the next Friday in SharePoint 2010

```
=TEXT([Date Evaluated]+(7-WEEKDAY(Created)),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score -1):

For a 2 weeks Advance do this:

```
=Today+14
```

Comment: not what I asked but ok.....

Answer (score -2):

```
=Today+(6-MOD(WEEKDAY(Today),7))
```

worked

Comment: Please use the comments section to post comments or give more details around your answer if you think it adds more value to the existing answers.