# Workflow - How to calculate next monday 10am?

Tags: workflow

SP 2010 - Workflow
I have a situation where I need to send a "Task Reminder" every monday only if the "Task" was not completed by next Monday 9:00am. Could you please provide some ideas on how to achieve this?

challenges: How to calculate next monday when document is uploaded to the document library any day of the week? and format the next monday datetime with 9am.

How does the SP workflow assigns due date when a task is created by the workflow?

I thought about parallel action (1 branch being "Request Review" and other branch being "Task Reminder"). But I dont want to workflow to sit here if the Reviewer completed her/his task before Monday 9am because workflow has to go through 4 levels of approvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are building a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow, this would be impossible to do with the out-of-box workflow actions. A developer could build a custom workflow action that could do this pretty easily, but that assumes you have a developer sitting around in your closet to do this.

Probably the easiest was is to put a calculated column on the list or library so you can tap the power of Excel functions. Then have the workflow read the calculated column.

Here is a related post on how to use a calculated column to calculate a future date:

[How to set the Default value of a Date/Time column to next Friday?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38145/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-date-time-column-to-next-friday)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It helped. Also, got help from this link as [today] or [me] gives error when creating calculated columns. This is a helpful link to overcome that issue http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/